# debug a dotnet core program in terminal

Tags: .net, linux, debugging, .net-core

I’ve recently setup omnisharp with nvim and wanted to try to develope a dotnet core application without the help of VS/rider/vs code.

Now i tried to google around but couldn’t find any real way to debug dotnet core applications from terminal.

What’s the correct way to debug one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is going to be a very painful experience. There's no real command line debugger available for .NET Core.

However, CoreCLR developers use a plugin for `lldb` (on *nix) that teaches lldb about a number of commands that it can use to help debug .NET code.

Essentially:

```
lldb /path/to/dotnet/dotnet
plugin load /path/to/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/*/libsosplugin.so
b SystemNative_ReceiveMessage
r run
clrstack
```

Further documentation:

- A tutorial: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/05/02/debugging-net-core-with-sos-everywhere/
- General setup instructions: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/debugging-instructions.md
- List of commands: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/ToolBox/SOS/Strike/sosdocsunix.txt

If you start using it, you will quickly realize how painful this is. It's almost worth using VS/Rider/VSCode just for the debugger, sadly.

Comment: Sigh...  I guess I'll go start learning about vscode then...

Comment: Is this still the case in 2022?

Comment: For a command line debugger? Yeah, I don't think things have changed much. There's no debugger for .NET that can compete with the feature-set and quality lldb/gdb provide for C.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [netcoredbg](https://github.com/Samsung/netcoredbg), a debugger released by the Samsung under the MIT license. The tool suports cli (command line), GDB/MI and VSCode Debug Adapterprotocol.

The sample usage are:

```
$ netcoredbg --interpreter=cli -- dotnet /path/to/program.dll
```

They released a [guide](https://github.com/Samsung/netcoredbg/blob/master/docs/cli.md) with more information.